# Where Clause on Indexed Date Field returns wrong records in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I've got an AcuXDBC server that provides ODBC access to some COBOL databases.  I do not control the Databases, nor the configuration of the tables.

One particular table, if I use SQL Server to query the table with a `WHERE` clause to specify a specific date, I get the expected results.  However, if I use MS Access to query the same table on the date column, Access returns every record, not just the ones with that date.

Other date columns in this table work normally. The only difference I see is that this particular Date Column has an index that allows duplicates. Whereas, the columns that work do not have any indexes on them.

I do not see why the presence of an index would cause the selection to fail.

In access the following query works as expected:

```
SELECT PUBLIC_ODH2DB.ORDER_NUMBER, PUBLIC_ODH2DB.POST_DATE, PUBLIC_ODH2DB.ENTRY_DATE
FROM PUBLIC_ODH2DB
WHERE (((PUBLIC_ODH2DB.ENTRY_DATE)=#2/3/2012#));
```

But this one doesn't:

```
SELECT PUBLIC_ODH2DB.ORDER_NUMBER, PUBLIC_ODH2DB.POST_DATE, PUBLIC_ODH2DB.ENTRY_DATE
FROM PUBLIC_ODH2DB
WHERE (((PUBLIC_ODH2DB.POST_DATE)=#2/3/2012#));
```

Both Entry_Date and Post_Date are defined as Date in the COBOL, but look like DateTime to ODBC.  The only difference I see is that Access reports Post_date to be Indexed (Dups OK).

Comment: Can you add to your question both the query that works and the one that doesn't?